# How to show author image on post homepage

Tags: wordpress, blogs, author, genesis

I am a novice in the programming world and I am working on a Wordpress blog. What I would like to do is show the author image to the side of their respective posts on the homepage.

Here is a screenshot of what I am referring to: 
http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=52f0g9&s=8#.U9HCs41dX6Q

Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

WordPress has a function to accomplish this easily. You need to add this to the template you'd like to show the author photo.

```
<?php echo get_avatar( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ), 32 ); ?>
```

`32` being the image size.

More information on the Codex: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_avatar#Return_Values